# How to create boolean condition using Java switch?

Tags: java

I am writing a code that uses the input parameters to generates the structure of the boolean conditions. I am currently using the Java scanner to ask the input and then use java switch command to generates the output results.

In the following code, The scanner looks for the input and then asks for the parameters values.

------------start of Code------------

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Code {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    char select;
    double size; 
    double days;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter char - or + or ||: ");

    operator = scanner.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.print("Enter size and days: ");

    size = scanner.nextDouble();
    days = scanner.nextDouble();


    switch (select) {

        case '-':
            System.out.print(size + "is less than" + days);
            break;

        case '+':
            System.out.print(size + "is greater than" + days);
            break;
        case '||':
            System.out.print(size + "and" + days + "are equal");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("enter valid amount!");
            break;
    }
}
```

}

------------end of Code------------

By compiling this code, it will give error as:

```
 Code.java:31: error: unclosed character literal
            case '||':
                 ^
```

I would like to know how can I handle this error.
My expected result at the end is that I can get the structure of boolean condition (that I stated at the beginning) created and save it into the object, then I can use it in my other code.
I will be more than happy if you could provide your help by code that I can understand the point easily.

Thanks

Comment: `'||'` is **not** a character -- it's **two** characters put together in an illegal way. Same for `&&`.  You're looking to use Strings, I believe, `"||"` and `"&&"`

Comment: Also, "Threshold < min && Threshold > max" that condition, if min<max, will never be true. Did you mean "min  < Threshold && Threshold > max" ?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for your comment. Yes, I am looking to use string. Now I applied your suggestion and I am getting an error as incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char".

Comment: @tryman Thank you for your comment. Yes, i am sorry it was a type that now i fixed. You are right "min < Threshold && Threshold > max" is correct.

Comment: Well, just using common sense, if you're case consists of Strings, then shouldn't the switch variable, operator, be one as well?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so what would you recommend that I should use to work in this case. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java makes a difference between a `char` which is denoted by single quotes (`'`) and a `String` which is denoted by double quotes (`"`). A `char` can only be one single character while Strings can have any length. Therefore, you should use double quotes instead of single quotes.

In addition to that, there's another issue in your code with the line `operator = scanner.next().charAt()`. This will only return the first character of the input, but `&&` and `||` are two characters. Therefore change your code as follows:

```
// ...
String operator;
// ...
operator = scanner.nextLine()
// ...

switch (operator) {
    case "||":
        System.out.print(Threshold + "<" + min + "||" + Threshold + ">" + max);
        break;

    case "&&":
        System.out.print(Threshold + "<" + min + "&&" + Threshold + ">" + max);
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid operator!");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments and code. I applied it but i am getting error as: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char
            case "&&":
                 ^

Comment: I edited my answer to fix that issue, too. Cheers :)